# django-rest-framework: Serializer data's "id" field returns null

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have an ObjectSerializer, which has a field for the 'id' field of the model Object (it's a ModelSerializer). Here's what's happening:

```
serializer = ObjectSerializer(data=request.DATA)
if serializer.is_valid():
  some_dict = {'field': serializer.data['field']}
  serializer.save()
  return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The response's 'id' field returns `null` for some reason? When I remove the line with some_dict, the response returns the id okay.

Not really sure what's going on here. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: NOTE: calling .copy() on the serializer.data dict also creates this bug

Comment: Answered on this issue: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is curious. The [default implementation of the `rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer` `data` property](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3fba60e99c75dda4e14f7fe4f941d6fc84e4c986/rest_framework/serializers.py#L488) just lazily populates the (private) `_data` member and returns that. Calling it twice in succession — which is essentially what you're doing — should return the same value the second time.

Can you reduce this to a failing test case and [submit an issue on Github?](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/new) — That would really help.

#### Update

Thanks for the report.

[As Tom noted in the discussion](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1116#issuecomment-24795835) you're seeing the issue because when you're accessing the data `save()` wasn't yet called, and so the `id` wasn't set. — Move the call to `data` after `save()` and you'd get the result you wanted.

Further to that, the behaviour has now been altered so that the cached `data` is cleared on a call to `save()` — this is fixed in `master` and should be in the next release.